# How to add contacts in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to save the contact number in mobile phone.

http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-making-use-of-the-contacts-plugin/

I am trying to save my contact number in mobile phone but i am getting an errors like this..I am placing an image u can look on that..[image]

Comment: you need to share line 16 of inline template in your AddContactPage class as the error says.

Comment: looks like you have an expression there like foo.create which is failing.

Comment: can you post your line of code so we can have a look at it.

Comment: can u please specify which line

Comment: var contact = this.contacts.create();

Comment: I m also facing the same problem. any solution

Answer (score 0):

looks like `this.contacts.create();` is failing where 'contacts' is undefined.Which means contact of type Contacts is not defined/null

have u checked your native plugin installation?

if its correctly installed try `Contacts.create()` rather than this.contact.create()